# display customized option value in shopping cart view

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-options

In shopping car view i can see only configure option that i selected in product page. i want to display customized option value too.
[image]

last option gem color is customized option.

while viewing cart
[image]

it display only 2 values. i want color value to display which i am selected.
 Can someone guide me to achiev this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom module and with help of layout and observer, you can display customized option value in the shopping cart view.

I assume you will create a custom module name "**Company_MyModule**".

So create an empty module with the name "**Company_MyModule**" (or anything you like) and after that follow the steps below to create other files.

**NOTE :** This solution only will not  works for configurable and grouped products.

**step 1)**

Create **catalog_product_view.xml** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/***

**File:** *catalog_product_view.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock> 
        <!--<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>-->
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 2)**

Create another layout file **checkout_cart_item_renderers**.xml to override cart item renderer under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/***

**File:** *checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <referenceBlock name="default" template="Company_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />
            <referenceBlock name="simple" template="Company_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**step 3)**

Creaete a template file **addtocart.phtml** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view***

**File :** *addtocart.phtml*

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       min="0"
                       value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- Custom Input Field -->
        <div>
            <select id="customizeoptions_color" name="customizeoptions[color]">
                <option value="red">Red</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="black">Black</option>
                <option value="white">White</option>

            </select>            
        </div>
        <!-- Custom Input Field -->
        <br>

        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

**step 4)**

Create another template file **default.phtml** for cart item renderer under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/cart***

**File :** default.phtml

```
<?php

$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$isVisibleProduct = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
/** @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $helper */
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data');
$canApplyMsrp = $helper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($product) && $helper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product);
?>
<tbody class="cart item">
    <tr class="item-info">
        <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Item')); ?>" class="col item">
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl() ?>"
                   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>"
                   tabindex="-1"
                   class="product-item-photo">
            <?php else:?>
                <span class="product-item-photo">
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml(); ?>
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                </a>
            <?php else: ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product-item-details">
                <strong class="product-item-name">
                    <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </strong>
                <?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                            <dt><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php if ($messages = $block->getMessages()): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
                        <div class="cart item message <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $message['type'] ?>"><div><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></div></div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
                <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
                    <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </td>

        <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
            <td class="col msrp" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')); ?>">
                <span class="pricing msrp">
                    <span class="msrp notice"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>
                    <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                    <a href="#" class="action help map" id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($helpLinkId); ?>" data-mage-init='{"addToCart":{"helpLinkId": "#<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $helpLinkId;?>","productName": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $product->getName(); ?>","showAddToCart": false}}'>
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("What's this?"); ?></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        <?php else: ?>
            <td class="col price" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')); ?>">
                <?php echo $block->getUnitPriceHtml($_item); ?>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="col qty" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>">
            <div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control qty">
                    <input id="cart-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
                           name="cart[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
                           data-cart-item-id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getSku() ?>"
                           value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getQty() ?>"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>"
                           class="input-text qty"
                           maxlength="12"
                           data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
                           data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="col subtotal" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal'));?>">
            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart msrp subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $block->getRowTotalHtml($_item); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-actions">
        <td colspan="100">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getActions($_item) ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**step 5)**

Creae event observer xml file **events.xml** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc***

In that file, we are declaring two events.

**File:** events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="company_mymodule_checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Company\MyModule\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="company_mymodule_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before" instance="Company\MyModule\Observer\SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**step 6)**

Create first event observer class file **CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver.php** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MuModule/Observer***

**File**: CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

class CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $_layout;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_request;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
     */

     /**
       * @var SerializerInterface
     */
     private $serializer;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
         SerializerInterface $serializer
    )
    {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }
    /**
     * Add order information into GA block to render on checkout success pages
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        /* @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
        //$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);

        $additionalOptions = array();
        if ($additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')){
            $additionalOptions = (array) $this->serializer->unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
        }
        $post = $this->_request->getParam('customizeoptions');
        if(is_array($post))
        {
            foreach($post as $key => $value)
            {
                if($key == '' || $value == '')
                {
                    continue;
                }
                $additionalOptions[] = [
                    'label' => $key,
                    'value' => $value
                ];
            }
        }
        if(count($additionalOptions) > 0)
        {
            $item->addOption(array(
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions)
            ));
        }
        return $this;
        /* To Do */
        // Edit Cart - May need to remove option and readd them
        // Pre-fill remarks on product edit pages
        // Check for comparability with custom option
    }
}
```

**step 8)**

Create another event observer **SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver.php** ( to save the custom option in order item table ) under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Observer***

**File** : SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $quoteItems = [];
    private $quote = null;
    private $order = null;

    /**
       * @var SerializerInterface
     */
     private $serializer; 

     protected $logger;


    public function __construct(        
         SerializerInterface $serializer,
         LoggerInterface $logger 
    )
    {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        $this->logger =  $logger;
    }


    /**
     * Add order information into GA block to render on checkout success pages
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {

        $this->quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $this->order = $observer->getOrder();
        // can not find a equivalent event for sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item
        /* @var  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem */
        foreach($this->order->getItems() as $orderItem)
        {
            if(!$orderItem->getParentItemId() && $orderItem->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
            {

                if($quoteItem = $this->getQuoteItemById($orderItem->getQuoteItemId())){
                    if ($additionalOptionsQuote = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options'))
                    {                       

                        //To do
                        // - check to make sure element are not added twice
                        // - $additionalOptionsQuote - may not be an array
                        if($additionalOptionsOrder = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options'))
                        {
                            $additionalOptions = array_merge($additionalOptionsQuote, $additionalOptionsOrder);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $additionalOptions = $additionalOptionsQuote;
                        }                        


                        if(count($additionalOptions->toArray()) > 0)
                        {

                            $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                            $options['additional_options'] = $this->serializer->unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                            $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function getQuoteItemById($id)
    {
        if(empty($this->quoteItems))
        {
            /* @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
            foreach($this->quote->getItems() as $item)
            {
                //filter out config/bundle etc product
                if(!$item->getParentItemId() && $item->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
                {
                    $this->quoteItems[$item->getId()] = $item;
                }
            }
        }
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->quoteItems))
        {
            return $this->quoteItems[$id];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

step 9) Run below command to compile and cache clean

php bin/mageto setup:di:compile
php bin/mageto cache:flush

[image]